# State Service SharePoint Foundation

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, session

I would like to ask, whether there is State Service in SharePoint Foundation. If yes, how I can run it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the Session State Service is only available in SharePoint Server 2010, not in SharePoint Foundation.